# Combine two tables by matching columns, keep unique columns from second table

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I am new to dplyr's join functions. I have two tables I want to combine

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c('Fred', 'Fred', 'Fred', 'Sasha', 'Sasha', 'Sasha'),
                  year = c('2018-19', '2019-20', '2020-21', '2018-19', '2019-20', '2020-21'),
                  outcome1 = 1:6)
df2 <- data.frame(name = c('Sasha', 'Sasha', 'Sasha', 'Rebecca', 'Rebecca', 'Rebecca'),
                  year = c('2019-20', '2020-21', '2021-22', '2019-20', '2020-21', '2021-22'),
                  outcome2 = 2:7)
```

so that the resulting table looks like this.

```
df3 <- data.frame(name = c('Fred', 'Fred', 'Fred', 'Sasha', 'Sasha', 'Sasha', 'Sasha'),
                  year = c('2018-19', '2019-20', '2020-21', '2018-19', '2019-20', '2020-21', '2021-22'),
                  outcome1 = c(1:6, NA),
                  outcome2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 3, 4))
```

I've found a solution to be `full_join(df1, df2, by = c('name', 'year')`, then to filter out Rebecca from the resulting table `%>% filter(name %in% df1$name)`, but is there a function that I can throw df1 & df2 into to get df3?

Comment: I don't think you can do this in just a single function call, and your solution of joining then filtering is a good one. A slightly different solution would be `full_join(df1, df2, by = c('name', 'year')) %>% semi_join(df1, by = 'name')`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `subset`, following the full-join action via `merge`

```
> subset(merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE), name %in% df1$name)
    name    year outcome1 outcome2
1   Fred 2018-19        1       NA
2   Fred 2019-20        2       NA
3   Fred 2020-21        3       NA
7  Sasha 2018-19        4       NA
8  Sasha 2019-20        5        2
9  Sasha 2020-21        6        3
10 Sasha 2021-22       NA        4
```